# rsync recursively copy files downstream of subdirectories matching pattern

Tags: rsync, file-copy

I am a novice to rsync and have a rather deep directory looking something like this:

```
source
  |
  +--foo
  |   |
  |   +--bar1
  |   |   | 
  |   |   +--bla (more dirs down the line)
  |   +--bar2
  |   |   |
  |   |   +--... 
  |   +--bar3
  |       |
  |       +--bla (more dirs down the line)
  ...
```

Now, I'd like to traverse/search the full path and recursively copy all csv files located somewhere inside/after a bla directory (i.e. in all directories sub to bla).
After reading some docs and posts on here, I thought that something similar to

```
rsync -ravm --include='/**/bla/' --include='*.csv' --exclude='*' source/ .
```

should do the trick, but whatever combination of includes and excludes I try, it either copies all CSVs from everywhere or nothing.

What am I not seeing here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am on bash 4.3.48 and rsync 3.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
rsync -avm --include='*/' --include='foo/*/bla/**.csv' --exclude='*' source/ .
```

or

```
rsync -avm --include={'*/','foo/*/bla/**.csv'} --exclude='*' source/ .
```

- `--exclude='*'` exclude all files
- `--include='*/'` include directories
- `--include='foo/*/bla/**.csv'`  include *.csv files in or below the `bla` directory
  (a relative `--include='bla/**.csv'` would work too if `bla` is always below directory `foo/barX`)

I removed option `-r` since it's already included in `-a`. And option `-m` removes all empty directories we might have found.

Comment: works like a charm, thanks!